# 301 redirecionamento de pagína de destino de subdominio

Tags: wordpress

Boa tarde, possuo um subdomínio que é um blog de wordpress, estou com problemas em fazer redirecionamento. No google developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed ele está me mandando esse aviso.

http://dominio.com.br/blog
http://www.dominio.com.br/blog
http://www.dominio.com.br/blog/

Como faço isso no wordpress tentei usar o plugin Redirection, mais não está funcionando.

Adicionei dessa forma 
url origem: dominio.com.br/blog/
url destino: www.dominio.com.br/blog

Comment: alguém que entende de wordpress?

Comment: a pergunta tá mal formulada. Tente ser mais claro... dificil ajudar assim.